# Hide device type from server?

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, mobile

I am trying to read on mobile browsers RSS feeds from SharePoint sites (like [this one](http://usermanagedsolutions.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/_layouts/listfeed.aspx?List=%7B97A06CC2-00B1-48B8-B72D-BE1E9D490EB8%7D)). The issue is that for some mysterious reason SharePoint doesn't serve RSS to mobile.

How can I work around this issue? Is there a way to hide the device type to trick the server?

[Edit] I am looking for a html or JavaScript solution, this is for public sites and I can't expect all visitors to change their mobile browser settings.

Comment: disable all scripting/plugins, and change your browser's ID string. I doubt sharepoint would be using script-based browser detection, though, so changing the browser ID should be enough.

Comment: You can change the `User-Agent` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to update the compat.browser file found in the web applications app_browser directory. You can learn more here

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393836.aspx